# iOS: Parsing JSON With AFNetworking and Retrieving Specific Information?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, afnetworking-2

I'm currently making a call to wunderground's API using AFNetworking's AFHTTPRequestOperationManager in the following way:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Everything is working correctly. My question is how can I pull out specific items from the responseObject. I'm trying to pull the following information "temp_f" and "temp_c".

> ```
> JSON: {
> "current_observation" =     {
>     UV = 0;
>     "dewpoint_c" = 19;
>     "dewpoint_f" = 65;
>     "dewpoint_string" = "65 F (19 C)";
>     "display_location" =         {
>         city = "Los Angeles";
>         country = US;
>         "country_iso3166" = US;
>         elevation = "70.00000000";
>         full = "Los Angeles, CA";
>         magic = 1;
>         state = CA;
>         "state_name" = California;
>         wmo = 99999;
>         zip = 90006;
>     };
>     estimated =         {
>     };
>     "feelslike_c" = "22.4";
>     "feelslike_f" = "72.3";
>     "feelslike_string" = "72.3 F (22.4 C)";
>     "forecast_url" = "http://www.wunderground.com/US/CA/Los_Angeles.html";
>     "heat_index_c" = NA;
>     "heat_index_f" = NA;
>     "heat_index_string" = NA;
>     "history_url" = "http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KCALOSAN8";
>     icon = hazy;
>     "icon_url" = "http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_hazy.gif";
>     image =         {
>         link = "http://www.wunderground.com";
>         title = "Weather Underground";
>         url = "http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png";
>     };
>     "local_epoch" = 1405410482;
>     "local_time_rfc822" = "Tue, 15 Jul 2014 00:48:02 -0700";
>     "local_tz_long" = "America/Los_Angeles";
>     "local_tz_offset" = "-0700";
>     "local_tz_short" = PDT;
>     nowcast = "";
>     "observation_epoch" = 1405410438;
>     "observation_location" =         {
>         city = "Downtown Los Angeles, Los Angeles";
>         country = US;
>         "country_iso3166" = US;
>         elevation = "343 ft";
>         full = "Downtown Los Angeles, Los Angeles, California";
>         latitude = "34.059711";
>         longitude = "-118.256401";
>         state = California;
>     };
>     "observation_time" = "Last Updated on July 15, 12:47 AM PDT";
>     "observation_time_rfc822" = "Tue, 15 Jul 2014 00:47:18 -0700";
>     "temp_c" = "22.4";
>     "temp_f" = "72.3";
>     "temperature_string" = "72.3 F (22.4 C)";
> };
> ```

Comment: Your posted JSON is a dictionary. So just use valueForKey method of dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The responseObject in your case is a `NSDictionary`. Just access it's objects using a key.

#### Example:

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

NSString *temp = responseDictionary[@"current_observation"][@"temp_c"];
```

Comment: Thanks reecon, but since temp_c is inside of current observations, how would that work?

Comment: Wow that looks super clean and straightforward. I appreciate the help!!!! Definitely a lot more simplified than a lot of other stuff I've seen!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

NSDictionary *CurrentObservation = responseDictionary[@"current_observation"];

NSString *strTempC = CurrentObservation[@"temp_c"];

NSString *strTempF = CurrentObservation[@"temp_f"];
```

OLD Type Coding

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

    NSDictionary *CurrentObservation = [responseDictionary valueForKey:@"current_observation"];

    NSString *strTempC =  [CurrentObservation valueForKey:@"temp_c"];

    NSString *strTempF = [CurrentObservation valueForKey:@"temp_f"];
```